# Split on pipe doesn't behave as expected

Tags: java, regex

I have a code that get a HTML content from a page, then get the index of a specific strings, after that it splits it.

My problem is, It's not splitting right, Plus it's getting unwanted Strings .

Code :

```
            URL = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ/view";
            html = Jsoup.connect(URL).get().html();
            FirstDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(html, "UTF-8");
            int Start = FirstDecoded.indexOf("[\"fmt_stream_map\"");
            int End = FirstDecoded.indexOf("\"fmt_list\"");
            String FirstSplit = FirstDecoded.substring(Start + 22, -5 + End);

            String[] DummyTexts = {"<html>","<head>","</head>","<body>","</body>","</html"};
            if(FirstSplit.contains(DummyTexts[0]))
                FirstSplit.replace(DummyTexts[0],"");
            if(FirstSplit.contains(DummyTexts[1]))
                FirstSplit.replace(DummyTexts[1],"");
            if(FirstSplit.contains(DummyTexts[2]))
                FirstSplit.replace(DummyTexts[2],"");
            if(FirstSplit.contains(DummyTexts[3]))
                FirstSplit.replace(DummyTexts[3],"");
            if(FirstSplit.contains(DummyTexts[4]))
                FirstSplit.replace(DummyTexts[4],"");
            FirstSplit.trim();
            String[] Splitted = FirstSplit.split("|");
```

What i want :

> Before Split

Url|Url|Url|Url

> After Split

[0] = URL
[1] = 2nd URL

Result (What i don't want ) :

```
<!html>*a new line*<head></head>*a new line*<body>*a new line**white space*URL|URL|URL*a new line**2 White Space*</body></html>
```

If i try to split it, [0] is null, [1] is `<!` .

The HTML is :

```
     <!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;">
   <meta name="fragment" content="!">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
   <title>OnClick.mp4 - Google Drive</title>
   <meta property="og:title" content="OnClick.mp4">
   <meta property="og:type" content="article">
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Google Docs">
   <script>(function(){(function(){function e(a){this.t={};this.tick=function(a,c,b){var d=void 0!=b?b:(new Date).getTime();this.t[a]=[d,c];if(void 0==b)try{window.console.timeStamp("CSI/" a)}catch(e){}};this.tick("start",null,a)}var a;window.performance&&(a=window.performance.timing);var f=a?new e(a.responseStart):new e;window.jstiming={Timer:e,load:f};if(a){var c=a.navigationStart,d=a.responseStart;0<c&&d>=c&&(window.jstiming.srt=d-c)}if(a){var b=window.jstiming.load;0<c&&d>=c&&(b.tick("_wtsrt",void 0,c),b.tick("wtsrt_",
 "_wtsrt",d),b.tick("tbsd_","wtsrt_"))}try{a=null,window.chrome&&window.chrome.csi&&(a=Math.floor(window.chrome.csi().pageT),b&&0<c&&(b.tick("_tbnd",void 0,window.chrome.csi().startE),b.tick("tbnd_","_tbnd",c))),null==a&&window.gtbExternal&&(a=window.gtbExternal.pageT()),null==a&&window.external&&(a=window.external.pageT,b&&0<c&&(b.tick("_tbnd",void 0,window.external.startE),b.tick("tbnd_","_tbnd",c))),a&&(window.jstiming.pt=a)}catch(g){}})();})();
 </script>
   <script>window.gapi_onload=function(){};var scriptEl$$inline_0=document.createElement("script");scriptEl$$inline_0.src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js";scriptEl$$inline_0.async=!0;var firstScriptEl$$inline_1=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];firstScriptEl$$inline_1.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptEl$$inline_0,firstScriptEl$$inline_1);
 </script>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_14_video_favicon.ico">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/file/client/css/2745349237-projector_css_rtl.css"> 
   <script>_docs_flag_initialData={"docs-aiiws":"docs_cold_nf","docs-ails":"docs_cold","docs-fwds":"docs_nf","info_params":{},"docosEmbedApiJs":"//docs.google.com/comments/d/AAHRpnXuhyO5yfTCPldRcxO-Xq_Srdd0JamOO8LslEPvYPeUzPnTtftedmIsqUWcNeSJHWF2hg2WdKe4Zpf5PRuBTzieIUoGG1g/api/js?hl\u003dar","docosUnreadCommentsEnabled":false,"uls":"","icso":false,"docs_oogt":"NONE","docs-egc":true,"docs-chat_wabel":false,"docs-ce":true,"docs-ut":2,"docs-chat_base_url":"talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/","docs-chat_domain_rotation":true,"docs-cwd":"","docs-epuv2":false,"promo_url":"","promo_title":"","promo_title_prefix":"","promo_content_html":"","promo_link_text":"","promo_element_id":"","promo_orientation":1,"promo_show_on_click":false,"promo_show_on_load":false,"show_promo":false,"promo_mark_dismissed_on_show":false,"promo_use_global_preference":false,"promo_close_button_text":"","docs-encp":false,"buildLabel":"texmex_2016.05-Thu_RC0","docs-show_debug_info":false,"ondlburl":"//docs.google.com","drive_url":"//drive.google.com","app_url":"https://drive.google.com/file/","docs-mid":2048,"docs-eicd":false,"docs-icdmt":[],"docs-sup":"/file","docs-uptc":["lsrp","noreplica","usp","urp","utm_source","utm_medium","utm_campaign","utm_term","utm_content","sle"],"docs-cwsd":"","docs-al":[0,0,0,1,0],"docs-ndt":"Untitled Texmex","docs-rpe":false,"docs-mdck":"","docs-mas":"","docs-etiff":false,"docs-spfe":true,"docs-mriim":1800000,"docs-eccbs":false,"docs-net-ernjp":false,"docos-sosj":false,"docs-rlmp":false,"docs-mmpt":15000,"docs-erd":false,"docs-erfar":false,"docs-ssi":false,"docs-ema":false,"docs-escd":false,"docs-ensb":false,"docs-epwf":false,"ecid":true,"docs-emo":false,"docs-eos":false,"docs-pedd":true,"docs-eir":false,"docs-dc":false,"docs-edll":false,"docs-eivu":false,"server_time_ms":1455582166639,"gaia_session_id":"","app-bc":"#d1d1d1","enable_iframed_embed_api":true,"docs-fut":"//drive.google.com#folders/{folderId}","esid":true,"esubid":false,"docs-etbs":true,"docs-isb":false,"docs-pid":"","docs-mib":5242880,"docs-mip":6250000,"enable_kennedy":true,"docs-gth":"","opendv":false,"onePickImportDocumentUrl":"","opmbs":5242880,"opmpd":2500,"opbu":"https://docs.google.com/picker","opru":"https://drive.google.com/relay.html","opdu":false,"opccp":false,"ophi":"texmex","opst":"000770F2037BC252B6F708ED31726B33CE13CDBE7A86BF0E7B","opuci":"","jobset":"prod","docs-se":false,"docs-ebcrsct":false,"docs-iror":true,"enable_client_docos":true,"enable_anchored_docos":true,"enable_docos_tickle":true,"enable_pinned_revisions":false,"enable_edit_blob_revisions":false,"upload_url":"https://docs.google.com/upload/resumableupload","enable_toolbar":true,"enable_link_opener":true,"enable_microscope":true,"enable_manage_timed_text":true,"video_embed_type":"PREFER_FLASH","enable_maps_embed":false,"maps_api_uri":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key\u003dAIzaSyBCjpnguVjzi6vS67NdBtyYuvCYz3yBxCY&sensor\u003dfalse","maps_display_uri":"https://maps.google.com/maps","docs-epcc":false,"docs_abuse_link":"https://docs.google.com/abuse?id\u003d0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ","enable_csi":true,"csi_service_name":"texmex","third_party_default_icon_urls":{"icon16":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_16.png","icon32":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_32.png","icon64":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_64.png","icon128":"//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/generic_app_icon_128.png"},"enable_chrome_webstore_link":true};</script>
  </head>
  <body dir="rtl" role="application" onload="_onProjectorLoad();" onunload="_disposeProjector();">
   <meta itemprop="name" content="OnClick.mp4">
   <meta itemprop="faviconUrl" content="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_14_video_favicon.ico">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/file/client/js/2068619951-projector_viewer__ar.js"></script> 
   <script>_initProjector({'id': '0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ', 'title': 'OnClick.mp4','isMobileWeb': true,'enableStandaloneSharing': true,'enableEmbedDialog': true,'projectorFeedbackId': '99950', 'projectorFeedbackBucket': 'viewer-web',},["",0,,1,1,1,1,,,1,0,[0,,0,"AIzaSyDVQw45DwoYh632gvsP5vPDqEKvb-Ywnb8",0,0,1,0,,,0,"/drive/v2internal",0,0,0,[0,0,0]
 ,0,1]
 ,1,5,1,,0,1,"https://docs.google.com",0,1,1,1,1,,1,20,1,0,0,1,1,[[,"0"]
 ,6,1,1,"ND"]
 ,0,0,1,,[0,,,,"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service\u003dwise&passive\u003d1209600&continue\u003dhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ/view&hl\u003dar&followup\u003dhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ/view"]
 ,0,1,1,600000,,"https://docs.google.com",0,0,[0,1,1,1]
 ,["https://youtube.googleapis.com",1,2]
 ,1,1,,0,1,1,1,0,,,,,[1,1,1,1]
 ,,1,0,2,0,0,[0,"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key\u003dAIzaSyBCjpnguVjzi6vS67NdBtyYuvCYz3yBxCY&sensor\u003dfalse"]
 ,0]
 ,[,"OnClick.mp4","https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/pI9y-A5tCOzi0W7eYAMzgqPHfzuBbq2wno4s2mvkrgc-JNtHtHWU36w0iICXMsRjxaAFuJ0p\u003dw1600-rw",,,,"0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ",,,,,"video/mp4",,,0,,"https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ/view",1,"https://docs.google.com/uc?id\u003d0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ&export\u003ddownload",[[["status","ok"]
 ,["hl","ar"]
 ,["allow_embed","0"]
 ,["ps","docs"]
 ,["partnerid","30"]
 ,["autoplay","0"]
 ,["docid","0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ"]
 ,["abd","0"]
 ,["public","true"]
 ,["el","leaf"]
 ,["title","OnClick.mp4"]
 ,["BASE_URL","https://drive.google.com/"]
 ,["iurl","https://docs.google.com/vt?id\u003d0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ"]
 ,["ttsurl","https://drive.google.com/timedtext?id\u003d0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ&vid\u003d1089c9d5a380c541"]
 ,["reportabuseurl","https://drive.google.com/abuse?id\u003d0B7--EhvK76QDRktKZm04MXVjVTQ"]
 ,["token","1"]
 ,["plid","V0QUM0REiMM2sQ"]

 ,["fmt_stream_map","37|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d37&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d3DC24BBB45AB0C09B1633ABC215282DAD3275086.1E524A3C98B38084443AF227B4676FA122CB7191&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,22|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d22&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d92CE58A6991267C1E6F28C23DC9C03F5CF7E0C7A.77E9DBA8D81F681587D68E2C9EF942DAA37D8461&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,35|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d35&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d92E5A471515BC4145F258D67C6E52F7CA0FA2530.73516C4866808CD98769225F3623A93613B65F1E&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,59|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d59&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d66DCB19D441D9742A4D21F1A08CDF488C81F728D.1864D7646337ED87C9A82951A0D524B6B3CEF451&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,34|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d34&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d1837C0B9C77AF259371C0239C7B56C68C43B86A0.68E22AF960C1C023033FD24D1138AFBE91CD02D3&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,18|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d18&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d9208D71BE0BCBE4B3DF1E7B922159C3BE921FA05.2A991F268E18F480929B6A98B107468601A55535&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,43|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d43&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d5720BE679324A8AE30BA464F81AE61CB6A551C1.69D6E187577E285BF9C2BF0415AD929EFA212D45&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18"]
 ,["fmt_list","37/1920x1080/9/0/115,22/1280x720/9/0/115,35/854x480/9/0/115,59/854x480/9/0/115,34/640x360/9/0/115,18/640x360/9/0/115,43/640x360/99/0/0"]
 ,["url_encoded_fmt_stream_map","itag\u003d37&url\u003dhttps://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=1089c9d5a380c541&itag=37&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=5.0.148.212&ipbits=8&expire=1455596566&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=3DC24BBB45AB0C09B1633ABC215282DAD3275086.1E524A3C98B38084443AF227B4676FA122CB7191&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hpa7ln7k&ms=nxu&mt=1455582034&mv=m&pl=18&type\u003dvideo/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"&quality\u003dhd1080,itag\u003d22&url\u003dhttps://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=1089c9d5a380c541&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=5.0.148.212&ipbits=8&expire=1455596566&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=92CE58A6991267C1E6F28C23DC9C03F5CF7E0C7A.77E9DBA8D81F681587D68E2C9EF942DAA37D8461&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hpa7ln7k&ms=nxu&mt=1455582034&mv=m&pl=18&type\u003dvideo/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"&quality\u003dhd720,itag\u003d35&url\u003dhttps://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=1089c9d5a380c541&itag=35&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=5.0.148.212&ipbits=8&expire=1455596566&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=92E5A471515BC4145F258D67C6E52F7CA0FA2530.73516C4866808CD98769225F3623A93613B65F1E&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hpa7ln7k&ms=nxu&mt=1455582034&mv=m&pl=18&type\u003dvideo/x-flv&quality\u003dlarge,itag\u003d59&url\u003dhttps://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=1089c9d5a380c541&itag=59&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=5.0.148.212&ipbits=8&expire=1455596566&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=66DCB19D441D9742A4D21F1A08CDF488C81F728D.1864D7646337ED87C9A82951A0D524B6B3CEF451&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hpa7ln7k&ms=nxu&mt=1455582034&mv=m&pl=18&type\u003dvideo/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"&quality\u003dlarge,itag\u003d34&url\u003dhttps://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=1089c9d5a380c541&itag=34&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=5.0.148.212&ipbits=8&expire=1455596566&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=1837C0B9C77AF259371C0239C7B56C68C43B86A0.68E22AF960C1C023033FD24D1138AFBE91CD02D3&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hpa7ln7k&ms=nxu&mt=1455582034&mv=m&pl=18&type\u003dvideo/x-flv&quality\u003dmedium,itag\u003d18&url\u003dhttps://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=1089c9d5a380c541&itag=18&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=5.0.148.212&ipbits=8&expire=1455596566&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=9208D71BE0BCBE4B3DF1E7B922159C3BE921FA05.2A991F268E18F480929B6A98B107468601A55535&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hpa7ln7k&ms=nxu&mt=1455582034&mv=m&pl=18&type\u003dvideo/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"&quality\u003dmedium,itag\u003d43&url\u003dhttps://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=1089c9d5a380c541&itag=43&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=5.0.148.212&ipbits=8&expire=1455596566&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=5720BE679324A8AE30BA464F81AE61CB6A551C1.69D6E187577E285BF9C2BF0415AD929EFA212D45&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hpa7ln7k&ms=nxu&mt=1455582034&mv=m&pl=18&type\u003dvideo/webm&quality\u003dmedium"]
 ,["timestamp","1455582166637"]
 ,["length_seconds","19"]
 ]
 ]
 ,5,0,,,,,,,,,,1,"mp4"]
 );</script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: *The DummyTexts replace result is being ignored

Comment: Without seeing the HTML you are trying to parse nobody can help you.  Also, with hardcoded offsets this code will break as soon as the HTML changes.

Comment: The replaces you are doing won't persist unless you load them into your FirstSplit variable. IE: firstSplit = firstSplit.replace("xxx","")

Comment: Please  follow naming conventions...

Comment: @AboHani Vaibhav was saying that the naming conventions for variables and methods are camel-case with an initial lowercase, and for classes are camel-case with an initial capital.  e.g. int start;  String lowerCamelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not spending too much time looking at your logic, I can see that you think

```
FirstSplit.replace(DummyTexts[0],"");
```

actually changes the String FirstSplit, which it doesn't.  In Java Strings are immutable, so they can't change.

Replace all those lines with something like this (obviously with different indexes in DummyTexts):

```
FirstSplit = FirstSplit.replace(DummyTexts[0], "");
```

Note that this doesn't *change* FirstSplit, it just changes what String FirstSplit refers to, setting it to the new String being returned by the replace method.  That might get you what you want, assuming the rest of that stuff works.

Ok, you say you changed to this and it still didn't work.  That's probably because the FirstDecoded string you're creating is basically the fmt_stream_map line from the HTML you listed (minus a few characters at the front and back):

```
"fmt_stream_map","37|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d37&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d3DC24BBB45AB0C09B1633ABC215282DAD3275086.1E524A3C98B38084443AF227B4676FA122CB7191&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,22|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d22&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d92CE58A6991267C1E6F28C23DC9C03F5CF7E0C7A.77E9DBA8D81F681587D68E2C9EF942DAA37D8461&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,35|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d35&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d92E5A471515BC4145F258D67C6E52F7CA0FA2530.73516C4866808CD98769225F3623A93613B65F1E&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,59|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d59&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d66DCB19D441D9742A4D21F1A08CDF488C81F728D.1864D7646337ED87C9A82951A0D524B6B3CEF451&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,34|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d34&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d1837C0B9C77AF259371C0239C7B56C68C43B86A0.68E22AF960C1C023033FD24D1138AFBE91CD02D3&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,18|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d18&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d9208D71BE0BCBE4B3DF1E7B922159C3BE921FA05.2A991F268E18F480929B6A98B107468601A55535&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18,43|https://r13---sn-hpa7ln7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes&id\u003d1089c9d5a380c541&itag\u003d43&source\u003dwebdrive&app\u003dtexmex&ip\u003d5.0.148.212&ipbits\u003d8&expire\u003d1455596566&sparams\u003drequiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature\u003d5720BE679324A8AE30BA464F81AE61CB6A551C1.69D6E187577E285BF9C2BF0415AD929EFA212D45&key\u003dck2&mm\u003d30&mn\u003dsn-hpa7ln7k&ms\u003dnxu&mt\u003d1455582034&mv\u003dm&pl\u003d18"]     ,[
```

This doesn't have any of the strings you're looking for in it....

Ok, so now you're wondering why splitting the whole page gives you crazy results, and it's because split() takes a *regex* argument, not just a String.  A single pipe '|' is not valid regex, use "\|" instead (escaped the special character).
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Just saw that Java Strings are immutable, and tried that already, it doesn't replace anything, The main problem is in splitting it which brings unwanted strings, I think that's why it's not replacing the right strings ( maybe ? ) .

Comment: I would suggest that's because the fmt_stream_map line doesn't HAVE any of the things you're searching for.  Check the html you put in there.

Comment: The HTML is in the OP, Please correct me if i'm wrong, After being splitted, the new String will be from the "start" int to the "end" int i've put, right? So the splitted one doesn't contain any of the strings i told him to replace, Then .. How am i getting "<html>" and other things after splitting ?

Comment: You got me wrong, Yes it won't replace anything because there are no matched strings in FirstDecoded, But i'm asking about splitting, You solved the second problem :P not them Main one, which is when splitting i'm getting unwanted strings like " <html > " >

Comment: That's probably because split takes a Regex and you're passing in a special character for regex.   Modified my answer.

Comment: Note, @AboHani    for the future, this would've gone a lot faster if just your original code was put in, not the added FirstSplit stuff.   That last line where you did FirstSplit.split("|") made it difficult to understand the supposed results you were getting.